# Combine two Observable that emit different types

Tags: java, rx-java

I have two Observables, one `Observable<String>`, one `Observable<Boolean>`. Can I combine them so I receive

```
@Override
public void call(String s, Boolean b) {

}
```

when both operations are finished?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you want to wait for items to be emitted from two observables (synchronizing them) you usually want something like [`Observable.zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html):

```
Observable<String> o1 = Observable.just("a", "b", "c");
Observable<Integer> o2 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Observable<String> result = Observable.zip(o1, o2, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

`result` will be an observable generating the application of `(a, b) -> a + b` to `o1`'s and `o2`'s items. Resulting in an observable yielding `"a1", "b2", "c3"`.

You can also use [`Obervable.zipWith`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zipWith%28rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func2%29) with an actual instance to get the same effect.

Note that this will terminate on the **shorter** observable when there is nothing to zip with.

Comment: Yay, works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Works only if the number of items into the first and second Observables are equal, otherwise you will lose emit items!!!

Comment: @sniper Added a notice. Thanks